# Mysql Join results as single row

Tags: mysql, join

I have a customer table

```
customers
+---------+
|   id    |
+---------+
|    1    |
```

And a varchar table

```
customers_varchar
+-------+-----------+
|  id   |   value   |
+-------+-----------+
|  1    | firstname |
+-------+-----------+
|  1    +  lastname |
```

Here's my select statement

```
SELECT c.id, cv.value FROM customers AS c
LEFT JOIN customer_varchar AS cv 
ON c.id = cv.id;
```

What I get is

```
ROW 1
1 | firstname

ROW 2
1 | lastname
```

What I would like is

```
ROW 1
1 | firstname | lastname
```

Comment: You will need to provide 1 more piece of information: The column name on how you identify first and last name, then you just join that together.

Comment: the column name in this example is value. My situation is a bit more complex but basically I need all the values from the varchar table to join to the user in the users table and output each user with their varchar values as single result

Comment: How do you identify a value as firstname or as lastname? You must have some meta info there...

Comment: I have an attribute_type table as well that can be joined to the varchar by attribute_id that identifies the type. Im not so concerned with this at this point as I just want all the values that match the users ID. Currently I can get all the values but they are returned as seperate rows for each value.

Comment: Does the order of the values matter? And do they need to be separate fields in the results?